# Generating all possible values from certain number

Tags: java

Does anybody know where to find a java algorithm for generating
unique values like this:
***0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 01 02 03 ... 99 001 002 ... 999 and so on...***
I am trying to get all possible, non-repeating combinations of all numbers from 0 to 999 and return them in an array.

I already searched everywhere but couldn't find it.
And sadly my IQ isn't high enough to make it by myself.
Thats my try below:

```
public int[] getUniqueIds(int amount){
    int[] arrayResultIds = new int[amount];
    int iteratorPosOfResultArray = 0;
    int idBefore = 0;
    int idToAdd  = 0;

    // First loop set values 0-9
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arrayResultIds[iteratorPosOfResultArray] = idToAdd;
        idToAdd++;
        iteratorPosOfResultArray++;
    }

    // 0-9
    // 00-09
    // 10-19
    // 20-29

    int iteratorPosOfWhileLoop = 0;
    String num = "";
    while (true){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            idToAdd++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think your example describes enough about the sequence in order to write code to generate your expected output. How does it get from 03 to 99? How does it get from 002 to 999? We'd need to make some assumptions about this sequence that could be right or wrong, it's hard to know with this definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small method will create all the numbers from 0 till the desired amount.

```
public int[] getUniqueIds(int amount) {
    int[] arrayResultIds = new int[amount+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        arrayResultIds[i] = i+1;
    }
    return arrayResultIds;
}
```

Comment: This code does not generate the output requested.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted algorithm creates an array of numbers in the range `[1..N]`, however it was requested to generate a sequence with leading `0` that is, a sequence of String needs to be generated/printed.

This can be implemented using `String.format` which allows to create "numbers" with the leading `0`s.

```java
public static String[] getIds(int limit) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int p = 10;
    int n = Integer.toString(limit).length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        String format = "%0" + i + "d";
        for (int j = 0; j <= Math.min(p, limit); j++ ) {
            if (j > 0 && j % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            String str = String.format(format, j);
            result.add(str);
            System.out.print(str);
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        p *= 10;
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    return result.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

The test will print the following output:

```
System.out.println(getIds(111).length + " elements");
```

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
10  
00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  
40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  
60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  
70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  
80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  
90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  
100  
000  001  002  003  004  005  006  007  008  009  
010  011  012  013  014  015  016  017  018  019  
020  021  022  023  024  025  026  027  028  029  
030  031  032  033  034  035  036  037  038  039  
040  041  042  043  044  045  046  047  048  049  
050  051  052  053  054  055  056  057  058  059  
060  061  062  063  064  065  066  067  068  069  
070  071  072  073  074  075  076  077  078  079  
080  081  082  083  084  085  086  087  088  089  
090  091  092  093  094  095  096  097  098  099  
100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  
110  111  
224 elements
```

Comment: You should probably end one value earlier.